# SPM Custom flag

Tags: swift-package-manager

I'm looking for a way to give custom flag to a Package using SPM.
I have different configurations, that target different environments: Staging, Integration & Production.

I've tried Swift Custom Flag, but the packages doesn't have access to them. I've read about swiftSettings but as I have more than 2 build configurations, I'm not sure that's the right solution for me.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks for helping.